# Calculate surface area of S = $\{ \frac{x^2}{a}+ \frac{y^2}{b}-2z=0, \frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}\leq1\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

At class, I have been proposed the following exercise:

**For all $a,b>0$, calculate the surface area of

$$S = \{\frac{x^2}{a}+ \frac{y^2}{b}-2z=0, \frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}\leq1\} $$**

How can I start formulating the answer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface area is given by

\begin{align}A=\iint_{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}<1}\sqrt{ 1+(z_x’)^2+(z_y’)^2}\ dxdy= 
\iint_{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}<1}\sqrt{ 1+\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}}\ dxdy
\end{align}
With the variable changes $x=au$ and $y=b v$
\begin{align}A=ab\iint_{u^2+ v^2<1}\sqrt{ 1+u^2+v^2}\ dudv= \frac{2\pi ab}3(2\sqrt2-1)
\end{align}